# What is correct way to query in React Testing Library with typeScript

Tags: react-testing-library, react-typescript, vitest

When writing tests with React testing library I wonder what is correct way to call queries. Take the following example.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import Avatar from './Avatar';

describe('<Avatar />', () => {
  it('should render Avatar component with proper content', () => {
    const props = {
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Doe',
    };

    const { getByTestId } = render(<Avatar {...props} />);

    expect(getByTestId('avatar')).toHaveTextContent('JD');
  });
});
```

It works as expected and test passes. I do get however error from my IDE - Webstorm.
`Argument type "avatar" is not assignable to parameter type HTMLElement.` It seems to suggest that `avatar` is passed as container to the query. [See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tx2CQ.png)

If i try to pass container to the query the test fails with `Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="[object HTMLDivElement]"]`

```
    const { container, getByTestId } = render(<Avatar {...props} />);

    expect(getByTestId(container, 'avatar')).toHaveTextContent('JD');
```

When I use getByTestId query obtained by importing it:
`import {getByTestId, render} from '@testing-library/react';`
And not using the getByTestId returned from render result the test again passes correctly. The IDE does not show any errors as well.

```
    const { container } = render(<Avatar {...props} />);

    expect(getByTestId(container, 'avatar')).toHaveTextContent('JD');
```

If this is the correct way to write queries then why does render method return getByTestId instance.

Comment: Update of vitest package seems to have fixed all the problems and Webstorm can correctly identify that 'avatar' is passed as id and not containter or HTMLElement